# Laravel MethodNotAllowedHttpException on put action

Tags: laravel

I begin with laravel and try to do a tutorial but on a old version (5.2).
So I try to translate with last version of laravel.

I have this error on an edit on a form:

> symfony \ Component \ HttpKernel \ Exception \
>   MethodNotAllowedHttpException No message

My route on web.php

```
<?php

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Web Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here is where you can register web routes for your application. These
| routes are loaded by the RouteServiceProvider within a group which
| contains the "web" middleware group. Now create something great!
|
*/

Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});

Auth::routes();

Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');

Route::resource('centres', 'CentresController');
```

My controller is Centrescontroller.php with

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use App\Http\Requests;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\centre;

class CentresController extends Controller
{



  public function index()
  {
      $centres = Centre::get();
     return view('centres.index', compact('centres'));
  }

  public function edit($id)
  {
     $centres = Centre::find($id);
    /// dd($centres);
    return view('centres.edit', compact('centres'));
  }

  public function update($id, Request $request)
  {
      return "Utilisateur modifié !";

  }
}
```

And my template with the form for edit is **/views/centres/edit.balde.php with**:

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')
<h1>Editer</h1>
{!! Form::open(['url' => route('centres.update', $centres), 'method' => 'PUT' ]) !!}

    {{ method_field('PUT') }}

    {!! Form::text('titre', 'titre',  $centres->titre) !!}

    {!! Form::text('slug', 'slug',  $centres->slug) !!}

    {!! Form::textarea('description', 'description',  $centres->descriptif) !!}

    {!!Form::submit("Envoyer")!!}


{!! Form::close() !!}

@endsection
```

I tried to add the put in two section because I found many message with this problem but it's not solving the problem.

My route list is good and centres.update must be ok so I don't understand the problem :

```
λ php artisan route:list
+--------+-----------+------------------------+------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------+--------------+
| Domain | Method    | URI                    | Name             | Action                                                                 | Middleware   |
+--------+-----------+------------------------+------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------+--------------+
|        | GET|HEAD  | /                      |                  | Closure                                                                | web          |
|        | GET|HEAD  | api/user               |                  | Closure                                                                | api,auth:api |
|        | POST      | centres                | centres.store    | App\Http\Controllers\CentresController@store                           | web          |
|        | GET|HEAD  | centres                | centres.index    | App\Http\Controllers\CentresController@index                           | web          |
|        | GET|HEAD  | centres/create         | centres.create   | App\Http\Controllers\CentresController@create                          | web          |
|        | PUT|PATCH | centres/{centre}       | centres.update   | App\Http\Controllers\CentresController@update                          | web          |
|        | GET|HEAD  | centres/{centre}       | centres.show     | App\Http\Controllers\CentresController@show                            | web          |
|        | DELETE    | centres/{centre}       | centres.destroy  | App\Http\Controllers\CentresController@destroy                         | web          |
|        | GET|HEAD  | centres/{centre}/edit  | centres.edit     | App\Http\Controllers\CentresController@edit                            | web          |
|        | GET|HEAD  | home                   | home             | App\Http\Controllers\HomeController@index                              | web,auth     |
|        | POST      | login                  |                  | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\LoginController@login                        | web,guest    |
|        | GET|HEAD  | login                  | login            | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\LoginController@showLoginForm                | web,guest    |
|        | POST      | logout                 | logout           | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\LoginController@logout                       | web          |
|        | POST      | password/email         | password.email   | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\ForgotPasswordController@sendResetLinkEmail  | web,guest    |
|        | GET|HEAD  | password/reset         | password.request | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\ForgotPasswordController@showLinkRequestForm | web,guest    |
|        | POST      | password/reset         | password.update  | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\ResetPasswordController@reset                | web,guest    |
|        | GET|HEAD  | password/reset/{token} | password.reset   | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\ResetPasswordController@showResetForm        | web,guest    |
|        | POST      | register               |                  | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\RegisterController@register                  | web,guest    |
|        | GET|HEAD  | register               | register         | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\RegisterController@showRegistrationForm      | web,guest    |
+--------+-----------+------------------------+------------------+----------------------------------------------------
```

Someone have an idea ?

Comment: Have you tried form model binding? I've not tried to use the Form::open on an update, but I think that might have something to do with it. Consider this code: `{!! Form::model($centres, ['method' => 'PATCH', 'route' => 'centres.update']) !!}`

Comment: I tried that and many more syntax but impossible. I have always MethodNotAllowedHttpException

Comment: Don't edit your solution into your question. Instead, post it as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution but i don't think it's very good.
If i write that in my template the form is ok and i have no error.

```
<form method="post" action="{{ route('centres.update', $centres->id) }}">


{!!  method_field('PUT') !!}
        {{ csrf_field() }}

        {!! Form::text('titre', 'titre',  $centres->titre) !!}

        {!! Form::text('slug', 'slug',  $centres->slug) !!}

        {!! Form::textarea('description', 'description',  $centres->descriptif) !!}

        {!!Form::submit("Envoyer")!!}


</form>

        @endsection
```

But i don't think that is good solution no ?

Answer (score 0):

I think

```
{!! Form::open(['url' => route('centres.update', $centres), 'method' => 'PUT' ]) !!}
```

should be

```
 {{ Form::open(['method' => 'put',  'route'=> ['centres.update', $centres], 'class'=>'form']) }}
```

And `$centres` is id right? If not then change `$centres` to something like `centres->id` in Form ( `'route'=> ['centres.update', $centres->id]` ) maybe that's the main reason.

Comment: No $centre is the main object. I tried your solution but same problem. I think it's a rpoblem on route but i don't understand why i can't acces to it

Comment: @christophe so why are you passing whole object in form? It should be just `id` i.e `$centres->id`

Comment: It was in my toturial with the version 5.2. It say it's possible to send object and the ID was detected by the framework. I updated with $centre->id but i have same problem.

Comment: Can you try changing `{{ method_field('PUT') }}` to `{!! method_field('PUT')  !!}`   or `@method('PUT')`

Comment: And i think you're also missing  `{{ csrf_field() }}` from the form!

Comment: Another suggest is change method in here `{!! Form::open(['url' => route('centres.update', $centres), 'method' => 'PUT' ]) !!}` to POST because you're doing it below via `{{ method_field('PUT') }}`

Answer (score 0):

Put this on the form `@csrf` . Here you can find more info about it https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/csrf